# Groovy StreamingMarkupBuilder will add namespace random

Tags: java, xml, groovy

I use **StreamingMarkupBuilder** for building a Xml.
But the problem is the xml namespace is added random in these inner fields.
I just want to have the namespace at the root node.

My code:

```
import groovy.xml.StreamingMarkupBuilder
import groovy.xml.XmlUtil
import java.time.LocalDateTime


def buildXml() {
    def mkpBuilder = new StreamingMarkupBuilder()

    mkpBuilder.encoding = 'utf-8'

    def clearingXml = mkpBuilder.bind { bld ->
        mkp.xmlDeclaration()
        mkp.declareNamespace(ns0: 'urn:document:rfc:functions')

        'ns0:rootNode' {
            fieldDynamic(LocalDateTime.now())
            fieldConst(123)
            fieldConst("abc")
        }
    }

    return XmlUtil.serialize(clearingXml)
}

println buildXml()
```

Below are the xml output from the groovy script:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><ns0:rootNode xmlns:ns0="urn:document:rfc:functions">
  <fieldDynamic>2023-03-07T11:18:01.462405</fieldDynamic>
  <fieldConst xmlns:ns0="urn:document:rfc:functions">123</fieldConst> <!-- Namespace is not need at here! -->
  <fieldConst>abc</fieldConst>
</ns0:rootNode>
```

I just want the **'ns0'** at the root node. But the namespace is not need at field **'fieldConst'**.